# Strange result when plotting data using "matplotlib.pyplot()"

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This is the array `real_stock_price_volumes`:

```
array([[1.32600000e+03, 3.19064498e+08],
       [1.32800000e+03, 9.90153760e+07],
       [1.33300000e+03, 1.34459291e+08],
       [1.32400000e+03, 9.76078850e+07],
       [1.32500000e+03, 1.25713918e+08],
       [1.30800000e+03, 9.14767100e+07],
       [1.31400000e+03, 1.16316712e+08],
       [1.29500000e+03, 9.86506690e+07],
       [1.25100000e+03, 1.00724864e+08],
       [1.19200000e+03, 9.36400500e+07],
       [1.22300000e+03, 7.32284280e+07],
       [1.23500000e+03, 3.02962310e+07],
       [1.22200000e+03, 4.39081200e+07],
       [1.20000000e+03, 1.33755011e+08],
       [1.16300000e+03, 5.22119140e+07],
       [1.15400000e+03, 3.74436890e+07],
       [1.13600000e+03, 3.67476700e+07],
       [1.11900000e+03, 3.74358580e+07],
       [1.09100000e+03, 4.77026620e+07],
       [1.08900000e+03, 4.50759280e+07],
       [1.07500000e+03, 7.15362200e+07],
       [1.07000000e+03, 3.64443230e+07],
       [1.06800000e+03, 3.88530380e+07],
       [1.06600000e+03, 5.20391440e+07],
       [1.06700000e+03, 3.48435300e+07],
       [1.06200000e+03, 3.50862750e+07],
       [1.05700000e+03, 3.11573250e+07],
       [1.07500000e+03, 5.02451850e+07],
       [1.07400000e+03, 4.20791170e+07],
       [1.06700000e+03, 4.64726370e+07]])
```

And this is the `predicted_stock_price_volume` :

```
array([[1.1192834e+03, 1.8556324e+07],
       [1.1616068e+03, 1.8931450e+07],
       [1.2031355e+03, 1.9183112e+07],
       [1.2409023e+03, 1.9258652e+07],
       [1.2728779e+03, 1.9135412e+07],
       [1.2981487e+03, 1.8822046e+07],
       [1.3164802e+03, 1.8347750e+07],
       [1.3283572e+03, 1.7757704e+07],
       [1.3345322e+03, 1.7099750e+07],
       [1.3357021e+03, 1.6413705e+07],
       [1.3322739e+03, 1.5725957e+07],
       [1.3248695e+03, 1.5064580e+07],
       [1.3142756e+03, 1.4456509e+07],
       [1.3013789e+03, 1.3922793e+07],
       [1.2871940e+03, 1.3477512e+07],
       [1.2722299e+03, 1.3122378e+07],
       [1.2567640e+03, 1.2853235e+07],
       [1.2409580e+03, 1.2661774e+07],
       [1.2249242e+03, 1.2538099e+07],
       [1.2087153e+03, 1.2471031e+07],
       [1.1924427e+03, 1.2452524e+07],
       [1.1762994e+03, 1.2476716e+07],
       [1.1604342e+03, 1.2539352e+07],
       [1.1450332e+03, 1.2637726e+07],
       [1.1303459e+03, 1.2769922e+07],
       [1.1166018e+03, 1.2934125e+07],
       [1.1039835e+03, 1.3127256e+07],
       [1.0926007e+03, 1.3344688e+07],
       [1.0826613e+03, 1.3583579e+07],
       [1.0743169e+03, 1.3840295e+07]], dtype=float32)
```

And I use this code to plotting them:

```
p1 = real_stock_price_volume[:,0]
v1 = real_stock_price_volume[:,1]
p2 = predicted_stock_price_volume[:,0]
v2 = predicted_stock_price_volume[:,1]
plt.plot(p1, color = 'red', label = 'p1')
plt.plot(v1, color = 'brown', label = 'v1')
plt.plot(p2, color = 'blue', label = 'p2')
plt.plot(v2, color = 'green', label = 'v2')
plt.title('Stock Price Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

But what do I get is this strange plot:

[image]

I say strange because my data are similar(p1,p2 and v1,v2) but the graphs are very different! What is the problem?

EDIT:
I also like to know how can plot `p1 & p2` in one plot and `v1 & v2` in other plot?

Comment: "_What is the problem?_" We can only guess. You haven't described what you were expecting. Your graph looks fine to me. (Due to differences in orders of magnitude and scale, +03 vs +07 vs +08). Perhaps your data isn't as _similar_ as you think it is. :-)

Comment: @TrebuchetMS: As I said in last line, p1 and p2 are similar, but blue and red lines are very different. And the same problem exist for v1 and v2

Comment: p1 and p2 are superimposed. That's why you see a purple line wayyyy near the bottom (they're both relatively close to 0 compared to v1,v2). v1 is one order less than v2. v1 is at +07 while v2 alternates between +08 and +07. No problem for me. Your graph looks all healthy and fine.

Comment: The red line (p2) is hidden under the blue line. It's v1 you're seeing.

Comment: I confused because it seems the color is changed when I try to plot 4 graphs. Blue should be the `p2` when I plot 4 graphs together.

Comment: My bad, The red line (p1) is hidden under the blue line (p2). It's v1 you see as red (it's brown actually).

Comment: Thank you. I got it. May you add the answer of second question to your answer too?

Answer (score 2):

Your data are not all that similar: the greatest value of v1 is about 30 times greater than the greatest value of v2.

As for p1 and p2, they are merged together on the graph. The red line (p1) is hidden under the blue line (p2). To see them apart, you can remove the two other plots:

```
plt.plot(p1, color = 'red', label = 'p1')
plt.plot(p2, color = 'blue', label = 'p2')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Similarly, to plot v1 and v2 in a separate plot, run:

```
plt.plot(v1, color = 'brown', label = 'v1')
plt.plot(v2, color = 'green', label = 'v2')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I confused because it seems the color is changed when I try to plot 4 graphs. Blue should be the `p2` when I plot 4 graphs together.

Comment: Please add your comment to your answer and also answer the second question if you can. Thanks. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not at all similar in the volume column.

For instance:

```
v2[0] = 1.8556324e+07 is 18556324
```

and

```
v1[0] = 3.19064498e+08 is 319064498.0
```

The difference is:

```
3.19064498e+08 - 1.8556324e+07 = 300508174.0
```

Comment: But what about the `p` columns?

Comment: I confused because it seems the color is changed when I try to plot 4 graphs. Blue should be the `p2` when I plot 4 graphs together.